# Best SEO sensible way of forwarding user when clicking an rel="shortlink"

Tags: seo, url

I have a question. What would be the best SEO sensible method of forwarding a user when the shortlink is clicked?

```
<link rel="shortlink" href="https://example.nl/&s=2415969336" />
```

I am currently doing:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.nl/nice-page">
```

But I am wondering. Is this a sensible way of doing so?

Comment: Similar problem: [Is a zero second meta refresh tag to 301 a Blogger post a proper solution?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98150/is-a-zero-second-meta-refresh-tag-to-301-a-blogger-post-a-proper-solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For humans, this is ok.

If you want the shortlinks to have the maximum impact on SEO, a 301 redirect would be ideal. The 301 would have to be sent directly in the HTTP header when the shortlink is requested.